# Process to map a transaction table to a status table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table, `TRANSACTIONS`, in SQL Server 2012 with ~100000 rows that has the following columns:

```
TRANSACTION_ID
TRANSACTION_DATE
PERSON_ID
FROM_STATUS_LK
TO_STATUS_LK
FROM_GROUP_ID
TO_GROUP_ID
ORGANIZATION_LK
TRANSACTION_TYPE_LK
```

I want to map each record to a table, `PERSONS`, with the following columns:

```
PERSON_ID
SEQNO
STATUS_LK
GROUP_ID
FROM_DATE
TO_DATE
ORGANIZATION_LK
```

The new table will have `SEQNO`'s that reset after each `TRANSACTION_DATE`. For example, if `N` transactions occurred on October, 20th 2014, then there would be `N` records in the child table with `SEQNO`'s from `1-N` for that date.

What SQL constructs could I use to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean how can you achieve linking the records together or how can you achieve a sequence number that resets?  Or are you needing help on both?

Comment: More the latter, but help with both would be good. My idea of for a solution consists of iterating over the entire table and manually inserting/updating by date/person id. Alternatively, I could sort the results by date first, and insert in order. In either case I don't know the correct syntax/constructs to achieve this. I looked up iterating over a rowset, but something seemed off about doing that in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with a sequence is that you have to specify the top end of the range and that's unpredictable in your scenario.  But you could track it on your own without having to worry about caching. Be sure to index and check as you see fit.

**CODE:**

```
--CREATE THE JOIN TABLE
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.PERSONS_TRANSACTION','U') IS NULL
    CREATE TABLE PERSONS_TRANSACTION 
    (
          SEQUENCE_DATE    DATE
        , SEQNO            INT
        , PERSON_ID        INT
        , TRANSACTION_ID   INT
    );
GO

--CREATE A PROC TO PERFORM INSERTS
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.usp_Insert_PERSONS_TRANSACTION','P') IS NULL
    EXEC sp_executesql N'CREATE PROC dbo.usp_Insert_PERSONS_TRANSACTION AS SELECT 1 STUB;';
GO

ALTER PROC dbo.usp_Insert_PERSONS_TRANSACTION  (@personID INT,@transactionID INT)
AS
    DECLARE 
          @today  DATE
        , @maxSeq INT;

    --GET THE DATE
    SET @today = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE());
    --PRINT @today

    --GET THE LAST SEQ NUMBER (NOT A TRUE SEQUENCE)
    SELECT @maxSeq = MAX(SEQNO)
    FROM PERSONS_TRANSACTION
    WHERE SEQUENCE_DATE = @today;
    --PRINT @maxSeq

    --IF THERE IS NO SEQENCE NUMBER IT HASN'T RESET YET, SO THE SEQUENCE NUMBER IS 1, INSERT
    IF @maxSeq IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT PERSONS_TRANSACTION
        VALUES (@today,1,@personID,@transactionID);
    END
    --IF THERE IS A SEQUENCE NUMBER, ADD 1 AND INSERT
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @maxSeq +=1;
        INSERT PERSONS_TRANSACTION
        VALUES (@today,@maxSeq,@personID,@transactionID);
    END;
GO

--ADD SOME TEST RECORDS
EXEC dbo.usp_Insert_PERSONS_TRANSACTION @transactionID=1,@personID=1;
EXEC dbo.usp_Insert_PERSONS_TRANSACTION @transactionID=2,@personID=1;
EXEC dbo.usp_Insert_PERSONS_TRANSACTION @transactionID=1,@personID=2;
EXEC dbo.usp_Insert_PERSONS_TRANSACTION @transactionID=2,@personID=2;

--MOVE THE DATE BACK A DAY TO TEST RESET
UPDATE PERSONS_TRANSACTION
    SET SEQUENCE_DATE = '2017-09-24';

--ADD SOME MORE RECORDS 
EXEC dbo.usp_Insert_PERSONS_TRANSACTION @transactionID=3,@personID=1;
EXEC dbo.usp_Insert_PERSONS_TRANSACTION @transactionID=4,@personID=1;
EXEC dbo.usp_Insert_PERSONS_TRANSACTION @transactionID=3,@personID=2;
EXEC dbo.usp_Insert_PERSONS_TRANSACTION @transactionID=4,@personID=2;

SELECT * FROM PERSONS_TRANSACTION;

--DROP TABLE PERSONS_TRANSACTION;
--DROP PROC usp_Insert_PERSONS_TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: This is great thank you. I am new to some of the syntax (SQL novice) but the I'm understanding the logic. Can you clarify what you mean by, "index and check"?

Comment: Your table is going to grow so you will want to set up an index to manage quicker reads, maybe clustered on Sequence_Date and SeqNo.  You'll also want to ensure duplicate values aren't getting inserted via logic or constraints.

Comment: What is SELECT 1 STUB? It's not just an alias, right?

Comment: STUB is just an alias for the column that would store the value 1.  It also acts to identify what you are doing - creating a stub proc for later revision. 
 It's just to make the CREATE statement syntactically correct.  You'll never actually execute that version of the proc.

Comment: I see, much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just create it all at once, is it a best practice to define the logic in an ALTER?

Comment: You could.  I like to write my code so I can rerun it as many times as I want without having to worry about what already exists.  My life for the last 18 months has been DLM and defensive SQL plays a big roll in repeatable consistent deployments.